# regex to start matching from last letter in previous match

Tags: regex

I have following regex

```
(\{\w*\}\s*[^{}]+\s*)\{?
```

and I am testing it on this string

```
this {match} is cool{match} but {match} this one is more cool
```

currently I am able to capture 2 groups -> `{match} is cool` and `{match} this one is more cool`, so as you can see group `but {match}` is missing.

Reason for this is because last matched character is `{`, so in next matching turn he will skip `{`, and won't be able to match until new `{` occurrence.

Does anyone knows how to force to match middle group also?

Debugging: http://regex101.com/r/hM5xE6/2

Comment: Are you trying to capture `but {match}` or `{match} but`? Because if it's the first one, that is different than the other patterns you have captured.  if you are trying to capture `{match} but`, then it's the same pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably just remove the `\{?` (and the `\s*` too); you also don't need the capturing parentheses:

```
\{\w*\}[^{}]+
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/hM5xE6/3).

If you want to enforce the match to end before a `{` or at the end of the string, you can use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that:

```
\{\w*\}[^{}]+(?=\{|$)
```

But you would only need that if you wanted to avoid a match completely if there are nested braces, like in `{{match} whatever}`, where the first regex would find `{match} whatever`.

Comment: Ok with the second solution. But I do think the OP wish to get the matches and an explanation about the ored lookahead could improve your answer

Comment: @Tensibai: What do you mean by "get the matches"? The regex gets the matches, it just doesn't (additionally) capture them in a group that would contain exactly the same text.

Comment: I mean having capture groups for later use, but without knowing the language used it is an assumption from my part, you're right. Edit, ooops, did not saw the link to regex101 at first, forgot about the explanation request :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `regular expression` to start matching from last letter in previous match

```
\{\w*\}[^{}]+(?=\{|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are including the next `{` in the regex (but not in the match), so it begins the next match on the character after, skipping the first `{` and not matching until you get to the second.

There's no need for lookaheads or anything like that.
If you remove the trailing check for `\{?`, you get all 3 matches (can also remove the `}` from the brackets and the last `\s*`):

`(\{\w*\}\s*[^{]+)`

(http://regex101.com/r/hM5xE6/7)

you can also use the following regex, depending on how specific you need to be with the capture:

`(\{\w*\}[\w\s]*)`

http://regex101.com/r/hM5xE6/5

Answer (score 1):

```
(\{\w*\}\s*[^{}]+\s*)(?=\{|$)
```

Try this.Use lookahead for 0 width assertion.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/18